# Array assertion in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a list of some objects - let's assume companies. Now I want to check if this list contains companies with some names but not taking order into consideration. Currently I'm using such construction:

`companyList.name.sort() == ["First", "Second"]`

Is there any operator in Spock or Groovy that allows me to compare arrays without order?

Comment: I've never really thought of using .sort() as much of a trouble. It's fairly terse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no such operator as far as I know. If the list doesn't contain any duplicates the following assertion may be used:

```
companyList.name as Set == ["First", "Second"] as Set
```

Or something like that:

```
companyList.name.size() == ["First", "Second"].size() && companyList.name.containsAll(["First", "Second"])
```

Comment: I wanted something shorter than ```.sort()``` :) Answer like use ~== would be great :)

Comment: Unfortunately there' no such operator. Will have a look in a minute.

Comment: IMHO `as Set` is the most logical, as it _states_, that order is not important

Comment: Yes, I think exactly the same.

Comment: Yep - it's not as cool as operator but code readability is good

Answer (score 17):

You can make use of Hamcrest support in Spock and use the `Matcher` designed explicitly for this case - `containsInAnyOrder`.  You need the following imports:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder
import static spock.util.matcher.HamcrestSupport.that
```

Then you can write your test code as follows:

```
given:
    def companyList = [ "Second", "First"]
expect:
    that companyList, containsInAnyOrder("First", "Second")
```

This has the benefit over using `.sort()` in that duplicate elements in the List will be considered correctly.  The following test will fail using Hamcrest but passes using `.sort()`

```
given:
    def companyList = [ "Second", "First", "Second"]
expect:
    that companyList, containsInAnyOrder("First", "Second")

Condition not satisfied:

that companyList, containsInAnyOrder("First", "Second")
|    |
|    [Second, First, Second]
false

Expected: iterable over ["First", "Second"] in any order
     but: Not matched: "Second"
```

If you're using `then:` instead of `expect:` you can use the `expect` instead of `that` import for readability.

```
then:
    expect companyList, containsInAnyOrder("First", "Second")
```

Answer (score 2):

Upvoted for @Opal answer, it's probably the best in all terms. As a curiosity I would only add an example of usage of **minus operator** to compare two unsorted lists:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class ComparingListsSpec extends Specification {

    def "should contain all companies in two unsorted lists"() {
        when:
        def companies = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
        def unsorted = ["ipsum", "sit", "Lorem", "dolor", "amet"]

        then:
        companies - unsorted == []

        and:
        unsorted - companies == []

        and:
        companies - unsorted in [[]]
    }
}
```

It also works if one of the lists contains redundant data.

Comment: i'd stay away from `-` for anything, that is not a trivial type. `assert [[x:0,y:0]]-[[x:1,y:1]] == []`

Answer (score 0):

Now there are dedicated matchers [available](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1372) in Spock:

You can compare list elements ignoring their ordering using the following operators:

1. `==~` - Strict match (accounting for duplicated elements, etc.)
2. `=~` - Lenient match (ignoring duplicates)

So `[1,2,3] ==~ [2,3,1]` is truthy.